# MongoDB connection error after minutes with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem connecting mongoDB with nodejs. All is going well but after 4 minutes (more or less) throws an exception:

> mongodb connection error: Error: failed to connect to [myserver]

the code for my conection:

```
var options = { 
server: { 


poolSize: 50000,

socketOptions: { 
  keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 300000 , autoReconnect : true
  } 
}, 
replset: { 
  socketOptions: { 
    keepAlive: 300000, 
    connectTimeoutMS : 300000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 600000
  } 
} 
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://heremidatabase.com/collection', 
function(err) { //callback error
    if (err) throw err;
}, options); //options

//Catch exceptions
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('mongodb connection error: %s', err);
process.exit();
});
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Successfully connected to mongodb');
  app.emit('dbopen');
});
```

I am using:

```
"express"    : "~3.4.4",
"mongoose"   : "~3.6.2"
```

Any idea about what is happening? (some values are boosted to test the connection)

Comment: Just to be sure: is your database called `collection` by any chance? Does it have any username & password? And is it open on the default mongodb port?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it just with the newest version of node.